# Unescape site title in "Join?" dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

You should probably unescape the site name in the title of the "You are not a member, join?" dialog in the Android application (it appeared with an `&amp;`)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?!

Comment: 1 snap = 1000 words!

Comment: What site exactly?

Comment: Musical Practice & Performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.7, thanks!

[image]